# How to dedupe a file and maintain original sort order in Hive?

Tags: sorting, hadoop, hive, mapreduce, bigdata

My data is already sorted by descending last_column and descending third_column. I want to de-duplicate the data set based on last_column while maintaining the original sort order. So for each last_column, i want the first row in that final output. 
I need to achieve this using Hive.
My data is:

```
10009,12/3/1959,Rodney,Purtle,M,8/28/1986,d007
10010,5/1/1954,Ahishek ,Kumar,M,12/1/1986,d007
10011,1/21/1955,Abhilash,Whatever,M,9/12/1989,d007
10016,5/1/1954,Ross,Hupchuck,M,12/1/1986,d006
10008,1/21/1955,Michael ,Gross,M,9/12/1989,d006
10014,1/21/1955,John ,Talburt,M,9/12/1989,d006
10013,5/1/1954,John,Doe,M,12/1/1986,d006
10015,12/3/1959,Daniel ,Pullen,M,8/28/1986,d006
```

Desired Output:

```
10009,12/3/1959,Rodney,Purtle,M,8/28/1986,d007
10016,5/1/1954,Ross,Hupchuck,M,12/1/1986,d006
```

My current code:

```
select * 
from 
(select *, row_number() over (partition by last_column order by desc)as r from table_name)s 
where r = 1;
```

The output I am getting is:

```
10014   1/21/1955   John    Talburt M   9/12/1989   d006    1
10010   5/1/1954    Ahishek     Kumar   M   12/1/1986   d007    1
```

Can anyone please help and suggest what i may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Utsav you can try the following query:

select * from (select *, row_number() over (partition by last_column order by third_column desc)as r from table_name)s where r=1 order by last_column desc;

Hope it helps!